# Openshift Connect To MySQL From Local Java Application

Tags: java, mysql, database, netbeans, openshift

I'm using a scalable app on openshift and I'm trying to access its database from a local app but I am having trouble setting up the connection. I need to access my MySql 5.5 database.

IDE: Netbeans 7.4

[image]

I am using the environment variable values for the connection. I have no trouble connecting to it using my JBoss app in Openshift. Any help would be much appreciated. Sorry for the incomplete info. I am new here in SOF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the `rhc` client installed (see [Client Tools Installation Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/Client_Tools_Installation_Guide/index.html) if not), you can have it port forward to the server via `rhc port-froward`. Use `localhost` as the Host and port number it tells you, with the user name and password supplied from [the application page](https://openshift.redhat.com/app/console/applications).

Note this will only work when running locally, and the the `rhc` command will have to be running as well
See also [10.13. Port Forwarding](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/User_Guide/sect-Port_Forwarding.html)

Comment: Hi. Thanks. I did the port-forwarding before but I didn't know I was supposed to use my localhost as host for the connection. Thank you, it's working now.