# Connecting openshift mysql to netbeans on mac

Tags: php, mysql, netbeans, openshift, sftp

recently I connected my openshift application to netbeans with sftp. Then I created a MySQL 5.5 cartridge on openshift. However, on netbeans when I try to access the environmental variables like so:

```
define('DB_HOST', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST'));
define('DB_PORT', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT'));
define('DB_USER', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME'));
define('DB_PASS', getenv('OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD'));
define('DB_NAME', getenv('OPENSHIFT_GEAR_NAME'));
```

I cannot access the openshift MySQL database or its environmental variables at all from netbeans. What am I missing? How do I connect MySQL database from Openshift to netbeans? I appreciate any help given. I tried to find the answer to this but to no avail. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at this:
[Openshift Connect To MySQL From Local Java Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24982398/openshift-connect-to-mysql-from-local-java-application)

Port Forwarding on OpenShift:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-port-forwarding.html